# Jquery drop callback of droppable method called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a view with below event. View Id is "folders-block". 
     my element is View are like this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </u>
 <ul>
     <li>
       <ul></ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Below is the event in backbone.

```
  events{
   "mousedown .all-folders": "dragCustomFolders"
  },
  dragCustomFolders: function(e){
    $('#folders ul li').draggable({
      cursor: 'move',
      drag: this.dragElement,
      revert: "invalid"
    });

    $('#folders li').droppable({
      drop: this.cardDrop,
    });
  }
```

When I drag an li from one ul to another ul drop is called only once. When I drag li element to another li element within same ul element drop callback function is called twice.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try set [`greedy`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy) option to true on the droppable definition:

> By default, when an element is dropped on nested droppables, each
>   droppable will receive the element. However, by setting this option to
>   true, any parent droppables will not receive the element. The drop
>   event will still bubble normally, but the event.target can be checked
>   to see which droppable received the draggable element.

Code:

```
$('#folders li').droppable({
    drop: this.cardDrop,
    greedy: true
});
```